# How to make asignment operator overloading work for continuous assignment

Tags: c++

Today I had an interview. I was asked to write a to make assignment operator overloading.

Suppose I have an 3 objects such as

`className obj1, obj2, obj3;`

Now I want to assign like this

`obj1 = obj2 = obj3;`

How to do it?

I wrote a program below, but it is throwing error as `error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘ab = ab1.overload::operator=((* & ab2))’`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class overload{
public:
    int x, y;
    overload operator=(overload &);
    overload(){x = 1; y = 2;}
};
overload overload::operator=(overload &ov)
{
    overload o;
    o.x = ov.x;
    o.y = ov.y;
    cout << o.x << "..." << o.y << endl;
return o;
}
int main()
{
    overload ab, ab1, ab2;
    ab = ab1 = ab2;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: just some style notes: class names capitalized (`Overload`), operator argument is typically called `rhs` (= right hand side).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're modifying a local object and returning it by value. You need to modify `this` object
and return a reference to it:

```
overload& overload::operator=(const overload& ov)
{
    this->x = ov.x;
    this->y = ov.y;
    return *this;
}
```

The error you get is because a temporary returned by a function cannot bind to a reference to non-const (hence the `const` in my example).

Comment: yes it did resolve the problem. could you please elaborate more.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you would to be elaborated on? I'm not sure where the answers provided fall short.

Comment: Don't forget to protect against self-assignment. :)

Comment: @Casey I don't think this particular class needs any special measures.

Comment: Yeah, but it's never a bad habit to put it in.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your assignment operator take a reference to non-const and returns by value. Since the value returned from the first assignment is treated as a temporary, the compiler won't bind a reference to it, so the second assignment fails. The usual form of an overloaded assignment operator is:

```
T &T::operator=(T const &other)
{
    ...
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make the overloaded operator return a reference. Then it should work.

```
overload& operator=(const overload& o) {
  //do my assignment
  return *this;
}
```